# NDSolve Stiff PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and have a hard time solving a stiff PDE using NDSolve after searching around for different stiff system methods. Below is the PDE and so far I have been getting the errors of 
`NDSolve::ndsz: At t == xxx, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.` It's been quite frustrating and any feedback is deeply appreciated.

````
(*parameter setup*)
pm = 0.64; 
p0 = 0.5;
tmax = (pm - p0)/pm;
Tanhm1[t_, t0_] := Tanh[500*(t - t0)] + 1;
T[t_] := 293 + 20*Tanhm1[t, 0.1*tmax];
R = 225*^-9; k = 1.381*^-23;
mu[t_] := (2.414*^-5)*10^(247.8/(T[t] - 140)); 
g = 9.8; rp = 1050; rl = 1000;
D0[t_] := k*T[t]/(6*Pi*mu[t]*R);
U0[t_] := 2*R^2*g*(rp - rl)/(9*mu[t]);
H0 = 28*^-6; pinf = 0;
A1 = 8.07131; B1 = 1730.63; C1 = 233.426;
pint[t_] := 10^(A1 - B1/(C1 + T[t]));
kg = 20*^-16;
delta[t_] := kg*H0/(rl *D0[t]);
E0[t_] := delta[t]*(pint[t] - pinf);
Pe[t_] := E0[t]*H0/D0[t];
Ns[t_] := U0[t]/E0[t];
K[p_] := (1 - p)^6.55;
Z[p_] := 1/(pm - p);
DP [p_] := D[p*Z[p], p];

(*PDE*)
pde = {D[p[t, x], t] + (x/(1 - t))*D[p[t, x], x] == 
    Ns[t]/(1 - t)*D[K[p[t, x]]*p[t, x], x] + 
     1/(Pe[t]*(1 - t)^2)*D[K[p[t, x]]*DP[p[t, x]]*D[p[t, x], x], x]};
bc = {Ns[t]*Pe[t]*p[t, 0]*(1 - t)*(1 - Exp[-1000*t]) + 
     DP[p[t, 0]]*Derivative[0, 1][p][t, 0] == 0, 
   Ns[t]*Pe[t]*K[p[t, 1]]*p[t, 1]*(1 - t)*(1 - Exp[-1000*t]) + 
     K[p[t, 1]]*DP[p[t, 1]]*Derivative[0, 1][p][t, 1] == 
    Pe[t]*(1 - t)*p[t, 1]*(1 - Exp[-1000*t]),
   p[0, x] == p0};
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{pde, bc}], p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 41, "MaxPoints" -> 101, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[p[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```
````

Comment: Removing `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"` seems to help.  Also, add the option `PlotRange -> All` in `Plot3D` to see the entire solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all the options to NDSolve, it works fine in version 8.0. Simpliy do

```
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{pde, bc}], p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[p[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the StiffnessSwithching method?

```
 sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{pde, bc}], p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
       Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]

 Plot3D[Evaluate[p[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
       PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: Sorry, @maeinss, i edited your code accidentally when trying to edit mine. Don't know how to undo.